# Determining the voltage of the capacitor for unregulated power supply

Tags: power-supply

Since the voltage at the output of the rectifier bridge changes periodically, I was wondering what the voltage rating of the capacitor should be. I guess the voltage of the capacitor should match (i.e., be at least equal to) the peak voltage at the output of the rectifier (and not, for example, its rms voltage). Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, peak voltage.

Plus some margin, because transformers output their rated voltage at rated current, and with no or very light load the voltage output is somewhat higher. And also because mains voltage has a tolerance so it is allowed to be higher than the nominal voltage.